# .htaccess login on directories that dont exist?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an application that rewrites URLS like

domain.com/manage
domain.com/backend

These directories dont actually exists so I can't place an .htaccess file in them to actually password it.

Any idea how I can require .htaccess login prompt for all urls with these matches?

```
www.domain.com/manage/*
www.domain.com/backend/*
domain.com/manage/* 
domain.com/backend/*
```

If you also know a way to ignore the .htaccess login prompt by IP that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetEnvIfNoCase` with authentication:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/?(manage|backend)/ SECURED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Password Area"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from  all
Deny from env=SECURED
```